# How to Adjust the Content Display When Using Enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I am using the [`enumerate` package](//ctan.org/pkg/enumerate).

I have figured out how to add opening and closing parentheses when displaying the number of each item, but I have not been able to figure out how to adjust where the second (and all subsequent) content lines of each item are displayed. More specifically, given the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{enumerate}[{(1.)}]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

I would like, if possible, to have all lines following the first, begin under the right-hand parenthesis (or thereabouts) instead of directly underneath where the first sentence begins.

Is there a way to do this---so that I may adjust from time to time (within the same document) where all subsequent lines after the first line begins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to achieve this with [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) since you can adjust the horizontal spacing as an optional argument as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*.)},itemindent=1em,leftmargin=1em]
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```